# How can I make image as background? App keeps crashing

Tags: android

I want to make image/picture as background but using `android:background="#ffff"` makes it white and it works. As soon as I change to `android:background="@drawable/background_image"` and run it, crash.

Comment: is background_image available in your draw able folder?

Comment: Yes it is placed there

Comment: Where did you set Image Background?

Comment: No Vladyslav, if I go back to #ffff it works. Nothing crashes

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: `Nothing crashes` - you just said that it is crashing in your title. The question I marked explains what your question is missing to be on-topic. As for now it is off-topic because it is missing exception stacktrace, related code, etc.

Comment: "As soon as I change to android:background="@drawable/background_image" and run it, crash."

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this][1] This helped to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with another image.

sometime when you have Image in Png extintion then change it to jpg extenction you need to invalidate/restart the android stdiuo

Comment: I fixed but now my picture from imageview isn't visable

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: As soon as you comment I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image is too big and it has high resolution, try compressing and resizing it http://resizeimage.net/ using this website and put the compressed image as background if that doesn't work also try to put the image in xhdpi or xxhdpi folder